# Why doesn't the mouseover event work when use closure in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures, onmouseover

I have the following code

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>        
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>

var lists = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i=0, len = lists.length; i< len; i++){
    lists[i].onmouseover = function(){
        console.log(i);
    }(i);
}
```

Expected result: when mouse over each `li`, I got 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 in the console, but I only got those number when refresh the page not in `mouseover`, anybody knows why?

Answer (score 4):

The "calling parenthesis" `(i)` after the function expression **execute** the function immediately and assign its return value as event handler (which is `undefined`). Here is an example with a function declaration, which makes it easier to see (hopefully):

```
function foo(i) {
    console.log(i);
}

// in the loop
lists[i].onmouseover = foo(i);
```

See how `foo` is called and the return value is assigned to `lists[i].onmouseover`?

You have to return a function from the immediately invoked function expression:

```
lists[i].onmouseover = (function(i){
    return function() {
        console.log(i);
    };
}(i));
```

or with a function declaration:

```
function createHandler(i) {
    return function() {
        console.log(i);
    };
}

// in the loop
lists[i].onmouseover = createHandler(i);
```

More info: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)

Comment: Is the return statement necessary? Can it be like this:
`code`(function(index){
        lists[ index ].onmouseover = function(){
            console.log(i);  
        };                    
    })(i);`code`  Sorry, I don't konw how to format code in the comment.

Comment: Yes, you can do that too, you must moved the immediately executed function "one level up". It doesn't change anything though, it still works the same way.

Comment: Thank you very much, Felix Kling, your replies are quite detailed, I think I got your point.

Comment: "must" should have been "just" in my comment. It does not matter where inside the loop the immediately executed function is, as long as it is there. Some people prefer to put it around the complete loop body (like you did in your example), others prefer to wrap it only around the code that really needs it. And again others (I would count myself to them) prefer to use a dedicated, named function, because it can make the code clearer. Anyways, happy coding!

Comment: Yes, you are right, writing clear code is a good way, which sometimes could avoid memory leak(I just learned in some article), Happy coding too!